# Automatically change code based on git branch

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have a code base with two branches: master and experimental.

For testing purposes I have to use a different database and apiKey. It's a hassle when I have to merge changes and it creates a conflict.

Is there anyway to manage this automatically based on the branch name?

In master it's:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/' + 'oysterDB');
apiKey = '123ZXC'
```

In experimental it's:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/' + 'testingDB');
apiKey = 'QWERTY123'
```

Comment: Consider using environment variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common way to achieve this is by reading the variables from a separate *untracked* file. For example:

1. Create a new file called `config.json`.
2. Update your application to read the variables from the new `config.json` file.
3. Add the new file to your `.gitignore` file so that you do not track it in the repo.
4. Create different versions of the file such as `config.json.master` and `config.json.experiemental`, and change the settings accordingly. If implemented properly you can commit these files along with the `.gitignore` change into the repo and that commit can be safely merged into *all* branches. (Consider omitting passwords or sensitive keys from the json files you are committing.)
5. Create a [post-checkout hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout). Inside this hook you can look at the currently checked out branch (perhaps using the command: `git branch --show-current`), and based on what it is you can copy the appropriate json file to `config.json` so your app will use that set of variables.

Once the above steps are implemented, as soon as you switch branches your `config.json` will automatically be updated, and **your `git status` will remain clean**.

**Tip:** Anytime you (or others) might want to override the configs yourself, you could disable the hook temporarily and edit `config.json` manually. Or, perhaps you could add another file to your `.gitignore` file called `config.json.local`, and setup your hook to copy that file in place when you're not on one of the two shared branches. That way every developer can have their own private copy of the config file that is untracked, if desired. (Please note the local version would be missing from fresh clones.)